# How to run my ruby code after Rails server start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried:

```
after_initialize do
  #code
end
```

But: (documentation)

> Some parts of your application, notably observers and routing, are not
>   yet set up at the point where the after_initialize block is called.

I need routing and logger in my code

Any ideas?

Comment: could you state your problem more explicitly.

Comment: I want on_server_start event.

Comment: Why would you want that? What do you want to do? Explain your problem and maybe there is a better solution than an "on_server_start" event.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares Here's an example: I want a STOMP subscriber that would start after the server has started and not when the console is running.

Answer (score 35):

See section 3.1 from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

I believe you would put this code in config/application.rb

```
config.after_initialize do
    # ....
end

# config.after_initialize takes a block which will be run after Rails has finished initializing the application. 
# That includes the initialization of the framework itself
```

Also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html

Comment: This also runs when the Rails console (`rails c`) is invoked.

Comment: ...and on rake-tasks, that depend on rails. Is there a dependable mechanism to get notified **only** when the server has started up?!

Comment: can we also have `config.shut_down ..` something like that? when rails server stop.

Answer (score 18):

[@house9's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8546460/450661) is correct, as pointed out by the comments, this will also execute when running rake tasks, console, etc.  I used the following to recognize when a server was actually being executed:

```
# application.rb
if defined?(Rails::Server)
  config.after_initialize do
    # Do stuff here
  end
end
```

Comment: This only works if started with `rails server` if started directly with puma, it does not... (and Puma::Server is always defined)

Comment: Also verified this does not work with Passenger (so likely not any server in production).

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to create a custom initializer. It's just a ruby file that lives under config/initializers/ and is executed exactly "on_server_start" event :)

Comment: As with @house9's response this runs in rails console and rake tasks that load the rails environment load.

Answer (score 4):

Lines added to `config.ru` will be run by the Rails server, but not by Rails console or Rake tasks that load the environment.

```
# config.ru
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path("../config/environment", __FILE__)
# your code here (after environment is loaded)
run Rails.application
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Rails 5 the default server is Puma, so code in `config/puma.rb` will be run just once, and only if the server is started.

Comment: This works wonderfully for me, unlike the other solutions. Thanks