# How do I know the git branch my rails server is running on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, server, git-checkout

Is there a way to figure out which git branch my local rails server takes all data and structure from?

Let's say I switch to another branch for some reasons while my local rails server is still running. I would like to know which branch was checked out at the moment I started the rails server.

For example, if it happens that I change the branch while the server is still active on another terminal, then I forget to restart the server and I want to try something out on the first branch which is different from the second branch, I would like to know the name of the first branch in order to understand why it behaves differently.

Of course the normal behavior would be to restart the server manually (`CTRL+C` + `rails s`) without keeping track of the previous branch name, but you know, you get confused when this happens and you wonder why it's so. Then you might like to know this information (i.e. if that branch differs from you actual one) simply to avoid further headaches...

Comment: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`?

Comment: @TomLord yes, but I want the branch name to be somehow stored the moment I run `rails server`

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to do that... (Why do you care what the branch was *when you started the server*? Surely you should only care about what the branch is **NOW**??) But place something in `congif/application.rb`?

Comment: @TomLord because for example, if it happens that I change the branch while the server is still active, then I forget to restart the server and I want to try something out on the second branch which is different from the first branch, I would like to know the name of the first branch in order to understand why it behaves differently. I'll update my question with this.

Comment: Also, what should I place in `config/application.rb`?

Comment: There are all sorts of reasons you need to restart the server; switching branches is just one (and usually a restart isn't even needed!). Rails migrations, javascript chances, flushing the cache, editing locally sourced gems, ..... As to what you should place in `config/application.rb` -- I don't know, you tell me? How do you want to store what branch you are on? Write to a file? A global variable?

Comment: Or, you could try to be pragmatic about this and [auto-reload the server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22511991/1954610) if specific files are changed (rather than just checking the git branch, which indicates nothing).

Comment: What you will find really helpful is to have the name of the current checked out branch be displayed in the terminal prompt. If you google 'show git branch in terminal prompt', you'll find loads of options. Here are a few - https://coderwall.com/p/fasnya/add-git-branch-name-to-bash-prompt
https://gist.github.com/justintv/168835 After you edit the .bashrc or .bash_profile file, you will need to load the changes which you can do with `source .bashrc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I ended up putting this in my code (following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543904/how-to-run-my-ruby-code-after-rails-server-start)):

in `config/application.rb`:

```
module SoundnotationBackend
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.after_initialize do
      ::Git_branch = `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
    end
  end
end
```

so I can call the `Git_branch` variable anywhere, e.g. in my `views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<% if Rails.env == 'development' %>
<%= Git_branch %>
<% end %>
```